# Showing progress percentage while downloading a file from iCloud?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, nsmetadataquery

I'd like to show a progress bar while a UIDocument is being downloaded from iCloud.

I tried keeping a reference to the `NSMetadataItem` from the query asking it for its attributes every second, but the key `NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentDownloadedKey` either does not exist, or it suddenly changes to `100` once the document was downloaded.

Relevant code:

```
 // get meta data item from query

 NSNumber *downloadProgress = [self.documentMetadataItem valueForAttribute:NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentDownloadedKey];
    NSLog(@"download status: %@", downloadProgress);
```

Comment: Show the code that you have developed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of polling the `NSMetadataItem` for changes, you should just listen for updates from the `NSMetadataQuery` and get `NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentDownloadedKey` once (and update the UI) each time you receive an update.

(I *think* existing NSMetadataItem objects are not updated as the download progresses, except to transition from downloading to fully downloaded).

Here is a way of listening to NSMetadataQuery updates using KVO:

```
// To register for KVO updates:
[query addObserver:self
         forKeyPath:@"results"
            options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
            context:nil];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    // check that "object" is your metadata query then:
    NSUInteger changeKind = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeKindKey] unsignedIntegerValue];

    switch (changeKind) {
        case NSKeyValueChangeSetting:
            // The whole array of results changed, update your model accordingly
            // ...
            break;
        case NSKeyValueChangeReplacement:
            // This is where you update your progress bar in most cases
            // Enumerate [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey], this is a list of NSMetadataItems that will have all the desired properties
            break;
        case NSKeyValueChangeInsertion:
            // Handle a new document
            // ...
            break;
        case NSKeyValueChangeRemoval:
            // Handle a removed document
            // ...
            break;
    }
}
```

If you still see the progress not updating, please file a bug with Apple.

Comment: The existing NSMetadataItem is updated. The download progress key appears once the item was downloaded. The original query does not receive updates often enough to update a progress bar. Also, in the query updates, there is no download percentage key.

Comment: How are you listening for updates on the NSMedataQuery? Using KVO? In my experience I do get enough updates for a progress bar (about a dozen a second).

Comment: Thomas, can you maybe add your code to your answer? I'm just polling the metadata item every 0.5 seconds (just as a start for testing)

Comment: Thanks for the code. I registered a callback to be called when new results appear for the query (like in Apple's docs). This works fine, except that the key `NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentDownloadedKey` does not exist most of the time, or at the end it suddenly appears with 100 as value. Guess I'll have to file a bug…

Comment: You should post your code sample. I'm really wondering if you're looking at the right NSMetadataItems...

Comment: I figured it out. My data files were too small. Although it took up to 5 seconds to download, the meta data query results only included the download percentage for larger files that took up to 1 minute to download.